# Array not storing object

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I take a bunch of `.CSV` files from a server, open them and save them to another server as `.XLSX`.  My issue is with:

```
'Get the folder object associated with the directory
Set objPickup = objFSO.GetFolder(pickUp)
Set objDropoff = objFSO.GetFolder(Dropoff)
```

I keep getting an error and i'm guessing it's because I am pulling in an array `pickUp`.

```
Sub ListfilesAndMove()
    'List all files in selected folder
    Dim objFSO As Object, objPickup As Object, objDropoff As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook, Dropoff As String, pickUp As Variant
    Dim LastRowMonthly46 As Long, b As Long, c As Long
    Dim ADay As Integer, AMonth As Integer, AYear As Integer, myDate As Date
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim B3 As Range: Set B3 = ws.Range("B3")
    Dim B26 As Range: Set B26 = ws.Range("B26")

    Worksheets("Menu").Activate 'Go to worksheet Menu
    'Make variable Pickup equal to value of B3
    With Application
        pickUp = .Transpose(ws.Range(B3, B26))
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(pickUp) To UBound(pickUp)
        Debug.Print pickUp(i)
    Next i

    Dropoff = ActiveSheet.Range("B28").Value
    Worksheets("Report").Activate 'Go to worksheet Report
    Worksheets("Report").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Menu").Visible = False
    'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objPickup = objFSO.GetFolder(pickUp)
    Set objDropoff = objFSO.GetFolder(Dropoff)
    'Set values for cells A1,B1 and C1 and align text
    Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").Value = "The files found in " & objPickup.Name & " are:"
    Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Worksheets("Report").Range("B1").Value = "Processed Yes/No"
    Worksheets("Report").Range("B1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Worksheets("Report").Range("C1").Value = "New File Location"
    Worksheets("Report").Range("C1").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Worksheets("Report").Range("C1").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

    'Loop through the Files collection
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each objFile In objPickup.Files
        Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
        'Open and Save File
        Dim Filename As String
        Filename = objFile
        If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
            File_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
            File_name2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
            FileLength = Len(File_name2)
            File_name2 = Left(File_name2, FileLength - 4)
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" 'Rename sheet
            With wb 'Save File
                'save file to dropoff location
                .SaveAs (objDropoff & "\" & File_name2 & ".xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
                .Close SaveChanges:=False 'close file
            End With
            Dim FSO As Object
            Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
            'Add Processed Comment
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2).Value = "Yes"
            'Add location of new File
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3).Value = objDropoff
        Else
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2).Value = "No"
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Apply wrap text to B1
    Worksheets("Report").Range("B1").WrapText = True
    Worksheets("Report").Columns("A:C").AutoFit
     'Clean up!
    Set objPickup = Nothing
    Set objDropoff = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What error? Where? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you need to loop through the array. You can't pass an array to `GetFolder`

Comment: Error 13 - type mismatch it fails at 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objPickup = objFSO.GetFolder(pickUp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why all that code is necessary; based on the explanation of what you need to do, you should only need to run two lines of code for each file:

- one to open the `.CSV`:

  ```
  Workbooks.OpenText "C:\yourPath\yourFile.csv", 65001, 1, , , , True
  ```
- and one to save as `.XLSX`:

  ```
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\yourPath\yourFile.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  ```

I don't memorize syntax for rarely used commands like this; instead I let Excel write the code for me using the Macro Recorder. I do the task once and then clean up the code that Excel generates (which resulted in the examples above).

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Workbooks.OpenText` Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Workbook.SaveAs` Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel)
- MSDN : [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code)
- MSDN : [**Revising Recorded VBA Macros**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros)